# Mule elestic search configuration

Tags: elasticsearch, mule

Is there  way we can connect mule 3.0 and elastic search to fetch data from Elastic search.

As part of a POC , i would like to connect mule and elastic search for fetchib data based on given request,

POST or GET calls are preferred

Thanks,
Nikhil

Comment: The current Mule 3.x version is 3.9. Mule 3.0 is a long forgotten version that probably no one has used in years. Please confirm the version for the question.

Comment: Also the question is unclear. What specific request or data? Why POST or GET are preferred? I don't think other HTTP verbs are adequate for requesting data and it depends on what Elastic Search provides.